# How to fix this TemplateSyntaxError at error in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I get this error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

add requires 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Screenshot:

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6L9D.png)

I want to add pagination there but i get this error again and again

Here is my **`html file`**

```
<div class="pagination">
    {% if buy_list.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1"></a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ buy_list.previous_page_number }}"></a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for num in buy_list.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if buy_list.number == num %}
            <strong>{{ num }}</strong>   
    {% elif num > buy_list.number|add: '-3' and num < buy_list.number|add: '3' %}
        {{num}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if buy_list.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ buy_list.next_page_number }}"></a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ buy_list.paginator.num_pages }}"></a></li>
    {% endif %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces after the [**`add:`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add) built-in filter in your template.

```
buy_list.number|add:"-3"

buy_list.number|add:"3"
```